# Meta Tags Property ERROR

Tags: facebook-like, meta-tags, doctype

Im trying to put the metas:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="one title"/>    
<meta property="og:image" content="image.jg"/>    
<meta property="og:description"   content="news portal"/>
```

But i have the error:
Error   6   Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Attribute 'property' is not a valid attribute of element 'meta'.

the doctype I have is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
```

I dont know how can i solve this error cause not recognize this attribute.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Stop using Facebook's non-standard extensions to HTML
2. Use a Doctype that references a DTD that includes Facebook's non-standard extensions to HTML (Neither the W3C nor Facebook provide one)

Comment: I want to use a doctype that includes fb non-standard extesions, but i dont know one. thanks

Comment: You will probably have to write one.

Comment: then, what are the non-standard extensions facebook? (Sorry im new at this.)

Comment: The bits that the validator is complaining are invalid are the non-standard bits.

Comment: Well I'm in a dead end. So no solution? I need to insert the tags so that when people click on the "like" button, tags appear correct and not those defaults facebook. Am I the only one who has happened this problem?

Answer (score 0):

[My pages](http://byrden.com/facebook-metadata.html) validate against a standard DOCTYPE and they contain the Facebook metadata that's causing you trouble. I'm using a later version of XHTML.

I did, however, have to trick the validator into ignoring the Like button.

David